# How can I upgrade my Ubuntu 10.10 to 12.04?

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade

I currently have an Acer Aspire dualbooting with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.10. I would like to have the advantage of Long Term Support that 12.04 provides and would like to upgrade the Ubuntu 10.10. My computer's memory is partitioned so that it is roughly 90gb for windows, 90 for ubuntu, and the rest(roughly 120gb) i use as a sort of "Shared space" so I can save and access files from both OS. I just want to know how to do the upgrade without ruining this set-up.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from one version of Ubuntu to another is called a distribution upgrade. It's a fairly simple process. There are only three rules:

1. You can only jump one revision at a time (X.04 to X.10 or X.10 to (X+1).04)
2. You can break the above rule by jumping from an LTS to an LTS (X.04 to (X+2).04)
3. You can not go backwards.

To perform the process, you can follow [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-10.10-maverick-meerkat-to-11.04-natty-narwhal-desktop-and-server-p2) guide, but it's the same for all versions of Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo vi /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
# ensure it reads: Prompt=normal
sudo do-release-upgrade

Wait

Reboot

Done.
```